# Converting an RGB image to Grayscale using opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to convert a color image (RGB, 24 bit, png) to grayscale using OpenCV. But I am getting unexpected results. I have tried the following 3 approaches, which all give the same result.
Method 1:

```
img=cv2.imread(file)
img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
plt.imshow(img)
temp=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(temp)
```

Method 2:

```
img=cv2.imread(file)
plt.imshow(img)
temp=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(temp)
```

Method 3:

```
img=cv2.imread(file,0)
img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(img)
```

The original image is:
[image]
The image I am getting after the above conversions is:
[image]

I assume the problem lies in the channels (BGR being default for OpenCV imread). I need a proper grayscale image. Any help is appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61505879/2836621

Comment: Also, you need to use `cmap='gray'` else you get the Viridis colormap.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem as mentioned in the link was that I was using another library.