# PIL Image.save() convert doesn't maintain RGB color

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save a numpy array as RGB image using PIL.Image.save(),but it the saved image is not RGB. How do I save the image as RGB ? I am receiving the image as numpy array.

```
image_with_detections = np.array(image_with_detections)
image = Image.fromarray(image_with_detections.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
image.save(save_path)
```

The [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xprG.jpg) to original image
The [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JToxQ.jpg) to image saved by Image.save()

Comment: Clearly, you have BGR data, not RGB.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61505879/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following

```
image_with_detections = np.array(image_with_detections)
image = Image.fromarray(image_with_detections.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
image = image[:,:,::-1]
image.save(save_path)
```

Comment: Just realized now that Mark previously posted a link to an answer that uses the same concepts

Comment: Getting the Error : image = image[:,:,::-1]
TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Got the error solved,just needed to subsscript the array before converting to PIL Image.