# If I read an image with opencv save it, and read it again, does this lead to the image being loaded in RGB ordering?

Tags: opencv

I was wondering, since I noticed that if I save an image with opencv, without reordering the images back to RGB, they're saved in BGR ordering.
Now I have opened and reordered (using `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`) and I am unsure if the ordering is correct?
Because if it switches the first and last channel (R->B) and saves it as (BGR) than on the second load this would be RGB again right?

I apologize if this is a bit of a silly question.

Many thanks in advance!

for example

```
image = cv2.imread(path) #RGB ->BGR
cv2.imwrite(image, path) # saves BGR
image = cv2.imread(path) # what is the ordering of image?
```

Comment: Can you show your full code? Opencv will always load as BGR (from what the image file holds). imwrite will also assume BGR ordering. So when you have an RGB image (e.g imread followed by cvtColor BGR2RGB) and imwrite it, you save an image that has the blue channel values in its red channel. If you imread that again, you will have RGB ordering in memory, compared to your very original image.

Comment: @Micka that is what I was thinking, thanks! You may add this as an answer and I'd accept it. edit: apologies, I think maybe I misread, if I imread without switching, save and imread again, then it is switched back to the original right?

Comment: Easiest is to remember that opencv doesnt hold any information about the color space, so neither cvtColor nor imwrite nor any other function can know whether the image is RGB or BGR or HSV or anything else, but it might assume a specific ordering.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61505879/2836621

Comment: @Micka thanks again, I added pseudocode with commenting, I would assume the second imread would render RGB?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I read this before posting, it was what made me wonder about the double save

Comment: In your code, image will be the same after both imread calls (if a lossless encoder like .png is used). imread reads from file format to BGR ordering. imwrite assumes BGR input and saves according to the image file fornat. imread then reads again from file fornat and orders to BGR.

Comment: I see, so the image will be BGR after the second imread? Thanks a lot! From the other question/answer I had assumed that it would flip each time, i.e. it just treated it as arrays.

Comment: basically: DO NOT use cvtColor. imread and imwrite handle everything. stick to BGR order in your matrices. normally, you have absolutely zero reason to mess with the order of the channels in any way. opencv handles everything (you get BGR in your matrices, regardless of what's in the file), and any intervention from your side just *causes* issues.

Comment: @Olli If that were the case, for every image file you read, you would need to know the number of times that it had been read and written by OpenCV just to get the channel ordering right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the following image

[image]

Let's try if it changes if we load it in opencv over and over again.

```py
im = cv.imread("blue.jpg")
cv.imwrite("blue2.jpg", im)
im = cv.imread("blue2.jpg")
cv.imwrite("blue3.jpg", im)
```

If I understood your question correctly, you assume that the second image, `blue2.jpg` is a red image. That is at least what you claim here

> I noticed that if I save an image with opencv, without reordering the images back to RGB, they're saved in BGR ordering.

### Results

`blue2.jpg`:

[image]

`blue3.jpg`:

[image]

### Conclusions

Merely reading and writing the image files does not change the order of the color channels of the result. i.e. `imwrite(imread(.))` does not equal to `cvtColor(im, cv.BGR2RGB)`.

Comment: that will actually demonstrate the opposite of your claim. imwrite can't react to this "wrong" order (it's not BGR, which is OpenCV's native order) because the numpy array does not know the channel order of its data. even worse, you're not even using imwrite for the second case, but matplotlib. THAT assumes RGB order, so the file in both cases will look right, because both writing methods were given data in the channel orders each expects.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I might have misunderstood the question. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I think the answer is correct now, the first one was wrong, I actually did something similar which led me to believe that it saves in bgr (used Pillow at some point). I'll accept this as it is a good answer now, and elaborates on the great comments I got already.