# Python cv2 imwrite() - RGB or BGR

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, ros, robotics

It is confusing how opencv works in python. I understand that `cv2.imread()` assumes that the image is in BGR. However, when i convert the image from BGR to RGB using `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`, and the try to save the image and then read it using `PIL`, the colors are inverted.

**Context:** I am building a ROS pipeline where I have to use opencv ROS bridge to get images as rostopics and then transform the images using PIL.

Please refer to the following code and output image:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image as im

image1 = cv2.imread('/home/ali/Pictures/rgb.png' )
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imwrite('/home/ali/Pictures/test_img_bgr_cv.png', image2)
image3 = im.open('/home/ali/Pictures/test_img_bgr_cv.png')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1), plt.imshow(image1)
plt.title('Image 1'), plt.xticks(\[\]), plt.yticks(\[\])

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2), plt.imshow(image2)
plt.title('Image 2'), plt.xticks(\[\]), plt.yticks(\[\])

plt.subplot(1,3,3), plt.imshow(image3)
plt.title('Image 3'), plt.xticks(\[\]), plt.yticks(\[\])

plt.show()
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xX8k.png)

Comment: OpenCV reads and saves snd renders images that are BGR in memory, but in the "right" format when saved or rendered. OpenCV doesn't manipulate the images at all, it just represents them differently in mrmory than other libraries do, but some other libraries also use BGR as base. For example afair OpenGL needs BGR for rendering.

Comment: with cv2.imwriteb of inage2 you write the image with inverted colors, because you inverted the colors with the cvtColor BGR2RGB call.

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61505879/2836621

Answer (score 2):

Actually there seems to be a misconception about `cv2.imread()`, cv2 reads the image in BGR format Yes, **but** when prompted to save the image or showing it using `cv2.imshow` it correctly renders them, the problem is in matplotlib partially. Because cv2 uses BGR color format and matplotlib uses RGB color format.

So what are essentially doing is :

1. Load an image in BGR
2. Convert the image into RGB
3. Save it as RGB.
4. Load it again as BGR
5. Viewing it inverted with matplotlib.

A better solution would be to remove `image3` as below :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

image1 = cv2.imread('rgb.png')
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imwrite('test_img_bgr_cv.png', image2)


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1) 
plt.imshow(image1)
plt.title('Image 1')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(image2)
plt.title('Image 1')

plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Regarding `cv2.imwrite` then use `Image.open()` although I believe it would add necessary complications, you can use the following :

```py
import cv2
from PIL import Image 

image1 = cv2.imread('rgb.png')
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imwrite('test_img_bgr_cv.png', image2)

im = Image.open('test_img_bgr_cv.png') # Load the Image normally
b, g, r = im.split()                   # Split the color channel, change to b, g, r, a in case of need for Alpha.
im = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))     # Reorder the color channels the way intended.

# .show() is for "testing" only
im.show()
```

The other one is more simple just flip the return of the `cv2.imread()` :

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image 

image = cv2.imread('rgb.png')[:, :, ::-1] # The slicing here is done to avoid the height and width of image just reorder them.
img = Image.fromarray(image)
img.show()
```

P.S.: Please be more accurate regarding what you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Hushm. Actually, I need to convert the cv2 images to PIL images (later to be transformed using pytorch vision). And for that I need to understand how cv2 is manipulating the images. As far as i understand, PIL `Image.open()` uses RGB format by default so I have to convert the BGR images to RGB anyway. I am just confused on how to keep the images same when going from cv2 to PIL. I want to understand how to keep the images same when: 1) i do `cv2.imread()`, then `cv2.imwrite()`, then PIL `Image.open()`.2) directly going from `cv2.imread()` to PIL `Image.formarray()`.

Comment: @robo1996 OK, Np. 
Now that you clarified let me just edit my Answer.